# Writing power set of $\{\emptyset,x,y,z\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

That $\emptyset$ is confusing me, should we consider $\emptyset$ as an element or should we discard it?

So here is my work:

$\mathcal P(\{\emptyset,x,y,z\})=\{\emptyset,\{ \emptyset \},\{x  \} ,\{ y \},\{ z \},\{ \emptyset ,x \},\{ \emptyset, y \},\{ \emptyset,z \},\{ x,y \},\{ x,z \},\{ y,z \},\{\emptyset,x,y  \},\{ \emptyset,x, z \},\{\emptyset,y,z  \},\{ x,y,z \},\{\emptyset,x,y,z  \}    \}$

Comment: Being listed between braces **it is** and *element* of the set.

Comment: The rule for *finite* sets is: $n$ elements => $2^n$ subsets.

Answer (score 1):

The power set of an $n$-element set always has $2^n$ elements. The empty set is also always an element in the power set of any set.

So yes, your work is correct, and since $\varnothing$ is an element of the original set, it gets considered like any other element.